# Building opencv 4.4.0-fatal error: opencv2/hdf/hdf5.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, build, mingw

I am using

- opencv: 4.4.0
- os: win11
- compiler: gcc 8.1.0

When I build opencv-4.4.0 by mingw32, the Windows Powershell would caution this error.

```
[100%] Building CXX object modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.obj
In file included from D:\opencv\source\opencv-4.4.0\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:38:
D:/opencv/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:16:10: fatal error: opencv2/hdf/hdf5.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/hdf/hdf5.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\python3\CMakeFiles\opencv_python3.dir\build.make:76: modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2271: modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:165: all] Error 2
```

Actually, I can't find this file hdf5.hpp in opencv-4.4.0. I find it in opencv-contrib-4.4.0, so I copy it to opencv-4.4.0 directory. It is useless.
What should I do to build upto 100% in this case ?